# Hyperlink a pdf on local drive to rmarkdown html output

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

I am trying to make the citation of my report in rmarkdown to hyperlinks of the pdfs. I try the following:

```
[the citation](thefile.pdf)
```

This works on my computer but if I send it to someone else the links don't work. I understand that I am not doing this properly, but this is how I do it for URLs. Is there any way I can have these pdfs attached to the rmarkdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to upload your pdf's to the internet somewhere, and then put that link in the parentheses in the code snippet in your post. That code you posted would only work if the person had the same file in the same place on their computer.

`[Your file](A google drive/dropbox link)`

Comment: Is there anyway I can attach the pdfs to the markdown itself? I don't want to have to upload all of these online. Some I cannot even share.

Comment: puting them all in a folder and sharing the folder would be the best bet then. just put the path to the other pdf that resides inside the folder